# Declaring public static as array in class / oop

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have this following class:

```
    Class myclass{
     public static $item_row_name = array(
            array('Item 1','Item_1','Help Label 1','#Item1'),
            array('Item 2','Item_2','Help Label 1','#Item2'),
            array('Item 3','Item_3','Help Label 1','#Item3'),
            array('Item 4','Item_4','Help Label 1','#Item4')
     );

   public static function pr_row($tableau){ 

                $var ='';

          foreach ($tableau as $row) {
            echo $count; 
            $label=$row[0];
            $name=$row[1];
            $help=$row[2];
            $balisecss=$row[3];
            $var.=$label;
            $var.=$name;
            $var.=$help;
            $var.=$balisecss;
return $var;
}
}
}
```

In an another file i have this code :

```
    $testtab3 = myclass::$item_row_name;
$display=myclass::pr_row($testtab3);
echo $display;
```

This loop only returns the first array

How can i declare correctly my array? Maybe with serialize...?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what you ask for. `$row` is `array('Item 1','Item_1','Help Label 1','#Item1')`, `$rowitem` is `'Item 1'` and `$rowitem[0]` is the first character.

You probably want

```
foreach(myclass::$item_row_name as $row) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

or

```
foreach(myclass::$item_row_name as $row) {
    foreach($row as $rowitem) echo $rowitem;
}
```

Comment: Ok but in another function i have this ...:
 public static function pr_item_row($tab){ 
    foreach ($tab as $row) {....

And in an another file i have :
       myclass::pr_item_row($item_row_name);
It return only the first array...